# How can I make this sql query with jpa ?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to create a query in my entities.

I have these following tables in mysql DB :

```
 Categorie : id, nom ...

 Article : num_code_barre_, categorie ...
```

In my entity Categorie :

```
...

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 30)
@Column(name = "nom")
private String nom;

...
```

In my entity Article :

```
...

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "num_code_barre_")
private String numCodeBarre;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "categorie")
private int categorie;

...
```

I have tested this sql query in my DB, it's work :

```
SELECT c.nom , COUNT(a.numCodeBarre)  FROM categorie c INNER JOIN article a ON c.id =        a.categorie GROUP BY a.categorie
```

But when I try to create a namedQuery in my categorie entity I receive an error in my output: "Synthax error parsing the query ..."

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.count", query = "SELECT c.nom , COUNT(a.numCodeBarre)  FROM categorie c INNER JOIN article a ON c.id = a.categorie GROUP BY a.categorie")
```

Someone have an idea how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ON" is not part of JPQL FROM clauses in JPA 1.0 or JPA 2.0. It is introduced in JPA 2.1 only and I doubt you're using that, since not fully released

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your SQL is causing a synthax error but you can try this JPQL statement:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.count", query = "SELECT c.nom , COUNT(a.numCodeBarre)  FROM categorie as c, article as a WHERE c.id = a.categorie GROUP BY a.categorie")
```